# How to correctly revert multiple merge to remote master

Tags: git, github, merge, git-revert

I have 5 branches master, branch-1, branch-2, branch-3 and branch-4.

I made some changes to branch-3 and merged to master and again did it twice, now I want to go back to the stage before all the 3 merge, I can checkout to that commit and create another branch which contains the data how I need it .

with

`git checkout 1ba671a79a0cc57129768ce1ad0218e17841e4d9`

and then

`git checkout -b "experimental-branch"`

I have all contents in the stage I want in experimental-branch but I want this in master branch. How I can do this ?

I want to reset my master to this commit "`1ba671a79a0cc57129768ce1ad0218e17841e4d9`" after that there are commits and merges which are not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to reset your `master` branch to this commit, then just use:

```
git reset --hard 1ba671a7
```

This will reset your `master` branch to this commit.  But keep in mind this will rewrite the history of this branch.  This means that it could cause problems for anyone else sharing the branch (I'm assuming that no one else is sharing at the moment).

To push the updated `master` you will need to use:

```
git push --force origin master
```

to force the branch to the repository.

If you are trying to revert commits on a publicly shared branch, you really should consider using `git revert` instead.

Comment: my experimental-branch does not have any thing to commit, do I need to commit again with `git commit -m 'all your contents'` ?

Comment: `I have all contents in the stage` ... what does this mean?  If you didn't do any work, why would you want to bring this branch back to the current `master`?

Comment: I do not want the changes I made after that commit and merges I do not want those.

Comment: So you want to reset your `master` branch to this commit, throwing away everything which happened after that point, is that right?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I gave you an answer above.

Comment: I am the only person working on this repository, so Is it safe for me to use reset hard and it will be done ?

Comment: Is this will reset only master or other branches too ?

Comment: This should _only_ affect the `master` branch.  Other branches derived from `master` after this point should still exist, they will continue to use the same commit objects which `master` used to use.  And if no one else is sharing your `master` currently this should be safe to do.